# jhipster: add @ElementCollection to existing entity

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster

I'm trying to use @ElementCollection manually because it's not mentioned in relationships section in jhipster documentation. I've changed java class,  tried to generate liquibase file with changes through **mvn liquibase:diff** and then included a relationship in the my entity.json

```
 "relationships": [

        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "contato_telefone",
            "otherEntityName": "telefone",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
            "otherEntityField": "telefone",
            "ownerSide": true
        }
```

entity class

```
 @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "contato_telefone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_contato"))
    @Column(name = "telefone")
    private List<String> telefone;
```

When I tried to run app I got a LazyInitiationException and relationship table **contato_telefone** was not created. Am I missing something? What I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

JHipster only supports relations between entities, so adding your relation to your entity.json cannot work, it should be removed.

So to make it work, you're on your own but JHipster should not get into your way. 
You must create a Liquibase migration file to create your table and reference this file from master.xml which I guess is what you've done.

The LazyInitializationException is a common mistake, have a look at [LazyInitializationException when using ElementCollection in Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742224/lazyinitializationexception-when-using-elementcollection-in-play-framework)